# I need a pagination algorithm help for my code?

Tags: javascript, algorithm, reactjs, pagination

my page and pageSize is provided by the component as callback, this is my code:

```
renderTodos(page=0, pageSize=3) {

 if(page) {
    this.setState({
      current: page,
      page: page
    })
  }
   var f = this.state.page*2;
  var x = this.state.page*2;
  console.log("page ", f)
  console.log("page ", x+1)

    return this.props.todos.slice(f,x+1).map((todo,todoIndex) => {
      return <Todo
        key={todo.id}
        {...todo} // pass all the todo property
        onClick={() => onTodoClick(todo.id)}
        onTrashClick={() => onDeleteClick(todo.id, todoIndex)}
        handleSelectedTodo = {this._handleSelectedTodo}
        isChecked={this.state.checkedIds.includes(todo.id)}
      />
   })
}
```

My problem is I have problem selecting the proper index, let's say I am on 2nd page(provided on callback along with pageSize) I want to select the 4th to 6th index because I have pageSize of 3, and when I am on 3rd index I want to select the 7th to 9th index and so on but I cannot figure out what algorithm to use. help?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

How about this?

```
renderTodos(page=0, pageSize=3
{ 
     if(page) { 
         this.setState({ current: page, page: page }) 
     } 
     var f = page * pageSize;
     var l = f + pageSize;
     return this.props.todos.slice(f, l).map((todo,todoIndex) => { 
         return <Todo key={todo.id} {...todo} // pass all the todo property
         onClick={() => onTodoClick(todo.id)} 
         onTrashClick={() => onDeleteClick(todo.id, todoIndex)
         handleSelectedTodo = {this._handleSelectedTodo
         isChecked={this.state.checkedIds.includes(todo.id)} /> 
     })
}
```

For page 1, pageSize 3: Index starts from 3(4th element) and end index for slice is 3+3=6. So slice will return elements at indices 3, 4, 5 (4th, 5th n 6th)